# Whats the state of cross platform app development in 2020?

Tags: mobile, cross-platform

Please consider the following requirements for a new app project:

1. Target platforms are Android, iOS and Windows (desktop).
2. The app must be able to run in the background on Android and iOS.
3. The apps user interface must look equal across all platforms (i.e. we want to avoid the platform specific looks).
4. We want to do as little platform specific coding as possible. However, we'll need to implement quite some custom UI widgets. In an ideal case, we implement the UI widgets just once and use them across all platforms.

Which cross platform development envirnoment can handle all of these requirements?

Unity would fit well, except for the running in background requirement, which disqualifies Unity. Maybe Xamarin would fit as well, I haven't worked with it, but a quick research on Google made me doubt it would fit the third and fourth requirement...

Your advise is welcome, Thank you.

**Before prematurely closing this question as off topic, please consider:**

- The requirements can be answered with facts. These ain't of personal opinion.
- These questions can only be answered by somebody with expertise on the topic.
- Google returns plenty of useless articles that fail to provide the required information.
- If this question can't be asked here, where else should it be asked?

So please leave the question open, somebody might be able to share something more valuable than an "off-topic" flag. Thank you!

Comment: This is not an answer, but you can see [Qt cross-platform framework](https://www.qt.io/). It also provide powerful way to create own UI elements [QML](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmlapplications.html)